# Syslog full of spam, slowing down PC

Tags: rsyslog

I recently upgraded my Desktop and Laptop to Ubuntu 21.04 and my logs are completely filled with message from gnome-shell, kernel and other programs.

I have appropriate filers in /etc/rsyslog.d/30-custom.conf like this:

```
:programname, isequal, "gnome-shell" stop
& stop
```

Rsyslog seems to be completely ignoring my filters however as the log is filled with 1000s of message like:

```
May 16 11:19:00 stephan-desktop gnome-shell[4377]: Can't update stage views actor ClutterActor is on because it needs an allocation.
```

10s of them per second! On my laptop with an SSD the drive is constantly having to write new log files and the my whole desktop has become sluggish and unresponsive.

I tried using ~ at the end of the filter line instead of 'stop' but it makes no difference.
I tried using the new format instead of the old one:

```
if $programname == "gnome-shell" then stop
```

Which also made no difference. If I purposefully put an error in that conf file (e.g. placing a & stop before another line) I see a warning on restarting the syslogd.service so I know it's being read.

I realize this is likely a gnome-shell addon and I could disable them one by one to find the issue, but why is rsyslog ignoring my filters? I have a lot of filters on my laptop to prevent syslog spam which I rely on to keep my computer running smoothly but since the update to 21.04 all of them are getting ignore.

I've been at this for hours, any suggestions or help would be really apprecaited.

Comment: anything in [this reference](https://www.rsyslog.com/newbie-guide-to-rsyslog/) which helps you?

Comment: Not that I can see. I've read through all the docs for rsyslog but can't find anything that could explain why the rules are being ignored.